# Jquery UI Auto Complete Binding All Data Instead of filtered Data .Please Check the following URL jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/TScb2/1/

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Jquery Auto Complete with external Txt file containing Json Binding All the Values Instead of filtered values
Please help in resolving the Solution Here is the data included in jslint

Comment: The link to your code doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't filtering the results from your ajax call since you are reading a text file. Either you filter server side or you filter in javascript code using jQuery function `$.grep()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

You have to wrap your `$.map()` function like this:

```
response($.grep($.map(UserProfilesData, function (item) {
 //alert(item.Name)
 return {
  label: item.department,
  value: item.Name
 };
}), function (a) {
 return a.value.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#findcontact').val().toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}));
```

Here's a jsfiddle of a working copy

http://jsfiddle.net/TScb2/4/

Comment: Hi, one more question if i need the Search based on name and department is it possible ?

Comment: Read grep definition, it returns a set of elements from the array that match the condition, so in the return condition just add an or conditional and look for the value in the label as well `|| a.label.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#findcontact').val().toLowerCase()) !== -1`